# Odroid-XU4, Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

Have an Ordoino-XU4 and wants to run ROS on it. Whitch UBUNTU 14.04 and ROS will be best to use on it.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262176/odroid-xu4,-ubuntu--14.04lts/) by [GT](https://answers.ros.org/users/27012/gt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-05-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using 14.04 Indigo is the LTS release to use. We have used that with turtlebots for a couple of years now and it has worked well.

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2017-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been using Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS with success on my project.

---

Originally posted by [twf](https://answers.ros.org/users/31836/twf/) with karma: 11 on 2017-09-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1